# Davical Sync-Token web request

Tags: httpwebrequest, synchronization, webdav, caldav

I am trying not to re-invent the wheel here...

I have found some nice documentation on CalDav sync implementation [there](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)

According to its website, DaviCal is rfc6578-compliant since v. 0.9.8 (see [here](http://wiki.davical.org/w/Release_Notes/0.9.8)).

I therefore first send my request to get the sync token as follows:

```
PROPFIND http://my_cal_srv/user/calendar_path HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <d:propfind xmlns:d='DAV:'> 
        <d:prop>
          <d:displayname />
          <d:sync-token />
        </d:prop>
       </d:propfind>
```

This returns data as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/user/calendar_path/</href>
  <propstat>
   <prop>
    <displayname>My Calendar</displayname>
    <sync-token>data:,9</sync-token>
   </prop>
   <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
  </propstat>
 </response>
</multistatus>
```

So far so good, I have a token, it's "data: ,9". So, let's just try to get changes since 8, the token I had when I queried the server prior to adding some event.

```
REPORT http://my_cal_srv/user/calendar_path HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:sync-collection xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:sync-token>8</d:sync-token>
  <d:sync-level>1</d:sync-level>
  <d:prop>
    <d:getetag/>
  </d:prop>
</d:sync-collection>
```

The answer is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/user/path/86166f9c-3e2e-4242-9a28-0f3bfb1dd67a-caldavsyncadapter.ics</href>
  <propstat>
   <prop>
    <getetag>"5ed2101b0c867e490dbd71d40c7071bb"</getetag>
   </prop>
   <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
  </propstat>
 </response>
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/user/path/cb354fab-b41d-49ad-8a4f-8d68c9090ea0.ics</href>
  <propstat>
   <prop>
    <getetag>"334892703f4151024e9232eab9b515a7"</getetag>
   </prop>
   <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
  </propstat>
 </response>
 <sync-token>data:,9</sync-token>
</multistatus>
```

After deleting an entry (so I get sync-token 10, and still compare using token 8), I get following result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/user/cal_path/86166f9c-3e2e-4242-9a28-0f3bfb1dd67a-caldavsyncadapter.ics</href>
  <status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>
 </response>
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/user/cal_path/cb354fab-b41d-49ad-8a4f-8d68c9090ea0.ics</href>
  <propstat>
   <prop>
    <getetag>"334892703f4151024e9232eab9b515a7"</getetag>
   </prop>
   <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
  </propstat>
 </response>
 <sync-token>data:,10</sync-token>
</multistatus>
```

So I am a little confused here as I don't really know how to interpret these results...

Could anybody please explain to me how to extract the sync info from here? It is a little hard to figure out the changes types because the ICS namings are unclear...

Thanks in advance for helping out... And merry X-Mas !
Regards,
N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you get a "data:,9" doesn't imply you can actually query "data:,8" or ,7 etc. Sync tokens are opaque and do NOT give you a versioning system (you need sth like [DAV Versioning Extensions](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc3253.html) for that).

DAV sync-tokens are a simple optimization technique - nothing more. They are completely opaque to the client and the server can expire sync tokens at any time (and is not required to save tombstones and such). Eg a server which can't store tombstones can simply expire tokens on DELETE requests.

The way you use sync-tokens is:

1. to figure out which child collections of a parent collection need to be re-synced
2. to optimize syncing of a the resources within a child collection

1) Which child collections need to be synced

Assume you have a collection of calendars (e.g. my_cal_srv/user/) and you do a PROPFIND Depth:1 on this collection, asking for the sync-tokens of the child collections. If those don't match the ones of your clients cache anymore, you know you need to perform a sync of just those child collections.

Note: do NOT use the token you got back from this request to sync the child collection (which is what you do above). It might have expired already. Within sync-reports only use tokens you got from sync-reports!

2) Optimizing syncing of the collection contents

Again: sync-token's are an optimization, nothing more. You always need to be prepared to get an (in)valid-sync-token precondition error (which means the server expired the token) and do a full refetch of the collection contents! And then compare that (URL,ETag) to your cached version to figure out what the changes are. (essentially all the steps you need to do when you have a server which doesn't support sync-reports).

If you get a sync-token in the sync-report results, you can then use it in the next sync-request. If the server still has the state, it'll just give you the changes. If it expired the token, it'll give you the sync-token error.

Note: In case it isn't obvious - in the very first sync-request you don't (can't) provide a token. You run the query w/o a token and get back all the contents. You do the same again if the server sends you an (in)valid-sync-token error.

Comment: All works fine here.
Note that for **DaviCal**, it appears that if the token has expired, the server automatically returns **ALL** events in the request. I tested the request with any random key and I never got an error response, but looking at the content, it always returns ALL events located on the server.

Comment: Major bug in DaviCal. How would a client figure out what resources got deleted when a token expired? To the client it would look like the token was fine and would process the results as a change-set (there is no indicator that the response contains everything).

Comment: 1) Fix the bug in DaviCal, 2.1) Detect DaviCal via the Server header and disable sync-reports in your client, or 2.2) [lame] run a full PROPFIND once in a while to detect deletes.

Comment: What about considering that elements returned are the actual server state. So I need to detect local collisions for events that are existing locally but do NOT exist on the server. For those collisions, 2 options: 1. the local version was modified BEFORE the last sync operation => DELETE LOCALLY; 2. the local version was modified AFTER last sync => collision where DELETE loses => reload to server
It's not a 100%, but its compliant with the standard collision procedure that DELETE always loses in case of doubt.

Comment: Option 1 would be the most common case and you would constantly loose data. Remember that the server only returns the *changes* if the token was valid. Which is the case more often than not (if it wouldn't be, you could go with the regular PROPFIND in the first place as the optimisation would not work). If you have 1000 events in your DB, your token is valid and 1 event got changed. You would delete the remaining 999.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify: locally, I keep a change timestamp as well as the last-sync time stamp. This allows me to detect collisions. If, indeed, all my 1000 elements were synchronised at last-sync and they disappeared on the server => indeed I'll delete 999 of them. If, however, all of them were modified AFTER last-sync, then I'd UPLOAD the 999 elements (as they were most probably created locally).

Comment: The 999 elements didn't actually disappear on the server. A sync report only reports server side *changes* when given a valid token. Please reread carefully what was written, and maybe just go ahead give it a try. If you always want all records, just use a propfind (or a sync report with no token, which is essentially the same)

Comment: Ok got it - there's no way to identify whether the change report is the list of changed events OR the full list.... So indeed, it's a big thing here! Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing a correct request. In your request you have:

```
<d:sync-token>8</d:sync-token>
```

But this should be:

```
<d:sync-token>data:,8</d:sync-token>
```

Aside from that, the first response you are getting tells you that:

```
These resources have been changed or newly created:
/caldav.php/user/path/86166f9c-3e2e-4242-9a28-0f3bfb1dd67a-caldavsyncadapter.ics
/caldav.php/user/path/cb354fab-b41d-49ad-8a4f-8d68c9090ea0.ics
```

The second response tells you:

```
This resource has been changed or newly created:
/caldav.php/user/cal_path/cb354fab-b41d-49ad-8a4f-8d68c9090ea0.ics

This resource has been deleted:
/caldav.php/user/cal_path/86166f9c-3e2e-4242-9a28-0f3bfb1dd67a-caldavsyncadapter.ics
```

Comment: Ok, digging back into it. So it means that the status tag is the one to look for: 

For added/updated entries I'll get status 200
<status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>

For deleted entries I'll get status 400
<status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>

Is this how you interpret the results ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It's all in the spec as well.