# CalDav sync-token expiry

Tags: httpwebrequest, synchronization, caldav, sabredav

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605220/davical-sync-token-web-request/27720483?noredirect=1#comment49876706_27720483), I asked about syncing data with a DaviCal server. I ended up concluding that there was a bug on DaviCal as when querying a CalDav server with an invalid sync token, the server should return an error but, instead, it returns the whole set of events on the server.

So I started looking for an alternative CalDav server. I use SabreDav. I followed their very handy tutorial [here](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/).

On there it says:

> Caveats
>
> Note that a server is free to 'forget' any sync-tokens that have been previously issued. In this case it may be needed to do a full-sync again.
>
> In case the supplied sync-token is not recognized by the server, a HTTP error is emitted. SabreDAV emits a 403.

That looks promising : exactly what I need !

So what I do is getting my sync-token which is `http://sabre.io/ns/sync/15`.

I then submit my `REPORT` query as follows (maybe that's where I do things wrong?!)

```
string syncToken = "http://sabre.io/ns/sync/15";
string body = " <d:sync-collection xmlns:d=\"DAV:\"> " +
              "   <d:sync-token>" + syncToken + "</d:sync-token> " +
              "   <d:sync-level>1</d:sync-level> " +
              "   <d:prop> " +
              "     <d:getetag/> " +
              "   </d:prop> " +
              " </d:sync-collection> ";
Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://my.sabredav.com/calendars/example/home/");
Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my_user", "my_pwd");
Request.Method = "REPORT";
Request.ContentType = "application/xml";
// set the body of the request...
Request.ContentLength = body.Length;
using (Stream reqStream = Request.GetRequestStream()) {
    // Write the string to the destination as a text file.
    byte[] encodedBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    reqStream.Write(encodedBody, 0, encodedBody.Length);
    reqStream.Close();
}
    
// Send the method request and get the response from the server.
Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

So when I send the request using the valid sync-token `http://sabre.io/ns/sync/15` I just got, I get an empty response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.or /ns/">
    <d:sync-token>http://sabre.io/ns/sync/15</d:sync-token>
</d:multistatus>
```

So far so good.

If I use a previous sync-token that I know was valid at some point (`http://sabre.io/ns/sync/14` in this case - by chance it is the previous number...) I get changes as expected:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
     <d:response>
      <d:href>/calendarserver.php/calendars/admin/default/23b351ee-7677-46e3-b5c5-5263e8fca351.ics</d:href>
      <d:propstat>
       <d:prop>
        <d:getetag>&quot;8d8d122a66625ca990252fae652cd2e5&quot;</d:getetag>
       </d:prop>
       <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
     </d:response>
     <d:sync-token>http://sabre.io/ns/sync/15</d:sync-token>
    </d:multistatus>
```

But the issue is, that if I use a RANDOM sync token that I definitely know has never been issued: `http://sabre.io/ns/sync/1234312231344324`

I get the SAME answer as when I was using the latest (current) token:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
     <d:sync-token>http://sabre.io/ns/sync/15</d:sync-token>
    </d:multistatus>
```

SabreDav says it's supposed to throw an error 403, but clearly, it's not what I get here... However, if I use INVALID sync-token format, say `token1234`, I do indeed get an error 403...

So the question is: HOW can I make sure my sync-token is still valid ? So, if the token is valid and nothing is returned, I know my local cache is up to date or, in case the sync-token is INVALID, I need to do full sync!

Comment: A server doesn't have to deal with random tokens, tokens are fully opaque to the client. Also, a server doesn't _have to_ expire tokens, it *can*, that is something different ;-) I'd guess that SabreDAV attaches an ever growing revision number to each change and the sync-token just refers to that. Of course the server probably has to delete tombstones eventually, but that could be a database maintenance process running independently. P.S.: quite likely still a SabreDAV bug.

Comment: Wrt the PS: a bug which doesn't affect a proper client! Also, don't do stuff like this "<d:sync-token>" + syncToken" - always properly XML encode the tokens, they could very well contain special XML chars.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in sabre/dav. Feel free to open a bug report so it's on our radar. It's never been a major concern, as 'well behaved clients' would never supply a sync-token that was never issued by us.

The reason it's happening, is because the digit is simply an ever increasing record id in our database. To fetch all the changes a simple sql query with a `>` is done.

If you explicitly want to test invalid tokens in your client, I would recommend to simply supply a sync-token with a completely different format (something that doesn't start with `http://sabre.io/ns/sync`).

Comment: Ok. I will of course NEVER use a sync-token that was never issued by the client. I must be able to test my client in case there is an expired sync-token - this is why I tried random numbers.
So what the question may simply be - **WHAT** makes the server to forget a sync-token and **HOW** can I test my client with an expired sync-token ?

Comment: I think Evert said that SabreDAV never expires tokens.

Comment: Ok so the sabreDav comment on the tutorial is meaningless?

Comment: @neggenbe the comment partially exist so clients will behave correctly when we _do_ start to automatically expire the tokens. That's as important as getting it right today. The behavior would be similar to providing an invalid token altogether. You can try my earlier suggestion to replicate that.